# How do these two parts of a sentence relate?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in [*Word by Word* by Kory Stamper](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HFxxDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22you%20are%20reading%20are%20in%20some%20low%20German%20dialect%20and%20you%20are%20no%20longer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK2aTLnpvjAhVMRxUIHTS5DAUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22you%20are%20reading%20are%20in%20some%20low%20German%20dialect%20and%20you%20are%20no%20longer%22&f=false);

> It will become clear to you, in the space between heart beats, why you are having a hard time with this entry: it is because you realise now that you do not in fact actually speak English – that the words you are reading are in some low German dialect and you are no longer certain that they mean anything.

It is an account of a lexicographer, to make the sense of "entry" clear to you. But I want to ask: does it mean that you are so obsessed with writing an entry that you forget the language you speak? And, more importantly to me, how does it relate to the part of the sentence after the dash?

Comment: I assume it's the sort of thing that can happen in any study or reverie, when the person suddenly has massive self-doubts about their competence and perhaps even identity. So Theoden, King of Rohan, asks in _The Lord of the Rings_ "Who am I, Gamling?" [[MovieQuote](http://www.moviequotedb.com/movies/lord-of-the-rings-the-two-towers-the/quote_14117.html)] You may even begin to question the outside reality ("Is this English, Greek ... or Gobbledygook?")

Comment: But I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for interpretation of a passage rather than a word or idiom etc. 'Comprehension'. It's probably an excellent question for _Literature SE_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross-post of the identical question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217124/how-do-these-two-sentences-relate) that already received an accepted answer before this one was posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual thing that happens to any frequently-repeated chunk of language. It's called "fatiguing" the system. Say any phrase or sentence out loud 25 times. As you listen, you will find the words becoming just sounds to you, until all you hear is their rhythm and acoustics.

Since you already know what the words mean, repeating the language stimulus doesn't necessarily load the language interpreter as usual, and interesting other programs can be accessed, often with surprising results. The phenomenon has been utilized for millennia; this is what's behind many mantras and chants.

In this case, a fatigued lexicographer loads an etymological analysis routine, with predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

The *space between heart beats* refers to how the mind can race ahead of a task you are performing. This is common with routine tasks that take less concentration. Here, the extra time is used for self doubt.

The colon starts an explanation of the idea. The hyphen is used to start a phrase to amplify the idea with examples without starting a new sentence.